# Google Places API Mis-tracking my Query Count

Tags: google-places-api

I tried running 1k queries in a loop to see how many google would track, and after running 1k queries, Google's Places API Console has me at 5.53k Queries.

```
require('open_uri)    

gr = build_query_list(1000) # a list of URLs for google places requests
gr.length
=>100

gr.each{ |r| open(r).read }
```

After running the above, the console shows 5.53k more queries than I started with.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with open(str).read rather than the API.  I started using the ruby gem and my problems went away.